# Determining if a limit does not exist.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble determining if the limit defined below exists. I do not believe it does, but I am not sure how to find 2 paths where the limits differ. I've tried $f(x, mx)$, $f(my, y)$, $f(x, mx^2)$, but nothing really seems to work.

Show that the limit does not exist:

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2 + (1-\cos(x))^2}{x^4 + y^2}
$$

I thought about parameterizing using polar coordinates, but I wasn't sure how to show that the $\displaystyle \lim_{r^+ \to 0}$ will depend on $\theta$ (and hence does not exist).

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Setting $y=0$ gives $\dfrac14$; setting $x=0$ gives $1$.

Comment: Hmm I thought we could not approach along constant paths?

Comment: What do you mean by constant paths?

Comment: If I set y = 0, then you are taking $lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: for y = 0, you applied Hospital?

Comment: Thank you. I guess I overcomplicated this question by approaching via paths.

Comment: You can apply L'Hopital's rule for y = 0, but it gets messy. It doesn't look like squeeze theorem is helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$1-\cos(x)
=2\sin^2(x/2)
$,
since
$\sin x \approx x$
as $x \to 0$,
$\frac{y^2 + (1-\cos(x))^2}{x^4 + y^2}
=\frac{y^2 + 4\sin^4(x/2)}{x^4 + y^2}
\approx \frac{y^2 + x^4/4}{x^4 + y^2}
$.

We can now apply a
standard technique
and let
$y = k x^2$.
This becomes
$\frac{k^2x^4 + x^4/4}{x^4 + k^2x^4}
=\frac{k^2 + 1/4}{k^2+1}
$
which will have
different values
for different values
of $k$.